# Standard method for automatic binding of C++ variable to boost's property tree value

Tags: c++, boost, properties

I just discovered the bost::property_tree and I really like that I can let user to configure the application by editing the config file as well as changing the variable via options when the application runs, and I'm able to save changed configuration back to file.

I can simply load the variable:

```
int foo = boost::property_tree::get<int>("foo", 5);
```

and save the variable back into the property tree

```
boost::property_tree::put<int>("foo", foo);
```

This is simple and neat in simple project, but in large project I would like to :

- Save all the configuration depending on current values of variables in the program
- Automatically (alternatively) update property_tree object when some bound variable's lifespan has ended.
- Reload property file and update all values in my program on request.

without the need of some global load/save functions that would have to contain custom save/load functions for all parts of the program that needs to work with property values (for obvious reasons).

I could imagine something like

```
class ExtendedPropertyTree : public boost::property_tree
{
    .. (some container of bindings) ... binded variables;
    void saveAll();
    void reload();
    ...
};

template <class T>
class PropertyBinding
{
    ...
    std::string propertyIdentification;
    T& value;
    ExtendedPropertyTree& propertyTree;
    ... // alternatively pointer to before/after update function
    ... // alternatively default value
   ... // Constructor/Destructor would register/unregister this instance in the ExtendedProperted Tree automatically
};
```

Some way to merge conflicts (when value to be reloaded by property file is changed in the program as well as in the config file) would have to be defined as well.

At this point I feel, like I'm reinventing the wheel, is there any way to do it without making custom classes like this?